# Rename Legend Values in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

With `ggplot2`, I have learned to rename the X-Axis, the Y-Axis and the individual legends. However, I also want to rename the legend values.

As an example, for simplicity I have used 0 for male and 1 for female in a dataset, and when I display it and map gender to an aesthetic, I don't want the legend to read 0 or 1 for the data values, but male and female.

Or, in this example below, instead of "4", "f" and "r" using "4 wheel drive", "front wheel drive", "rear wheel drive" would make the graph much easier to understand.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data = mpg) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = drv)) + labs(x = "Engine Size (Liters)", y = "Fuel Efficiency (Miles per Gallon)", color = "Drive")
```

[image]

- One option would be to open the Excel file and change all the 0s and 1s in the specific column to "male" and "female".
- Another option would be to rename the values within R, but I have absolutely no idea how to do this. I'm very new to R.

What I'm hoping for is a simple way to rename the values displayed in the legend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `labels` argument in a scale to customise labelling. You can provide a function or a character vector to the `labels` argument.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data = mpg) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = drv)) + 
  labs(x = "Engine Size (Liters)", y = "Fuel Efficiency (Miles per Gallon)", color = "Drive") +
  scale_colour_discrete(
    labels = c("4" = "4 wheel drive",
               "f" = "front wheel drive",
               "r" = "rear wheel drive")
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much. Just for me to make sure I understand: the same would work with `scale_shape_discrete`, `scale_linetype_discrete` and so on?

Comment: Yes it would even work with continuous scales (but should match the length of the calculated or provided breaks) and the position scales (`scale_x/y_discrete/continuous`). So, any scale that produces labels essentially.

Answer (score 4):

You could `recode` the values before plotting :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mpg %>%
  mutate(drv = recode(drv, "4" = "4 wheel drive", 
                            "f" = "front wheel drive", 
                            "r" = "rear wheel drive")) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = drv)) + 
  labs(x = "Engine Size (Liters)", 
       y = "Fuel Efficiency (Miles per Gallon)", 
       color = "Drive")
```

[image]